# Initializations in functions and procedures

Tags: exception, ada2012, ada95

How does Ada handle an initialization in a function or procedure when there is an exception before the begin block? Is it the stack trace the same, if the assignment was done inside the begin block.

For example, I like to define constants whenever I can for locally declared functions and procedures.

function xyz(....) is
myvalue : constant Boolean := SomeFunctionReturnBool(...);

begin
...
except

end

If SomeFunctionReturn(Bool() throws an exception... will the exception get caught in SomeFunctionReturnBool's exception handler, if one is present, or will the exception get handled in the xyz exception block.

Asking for a friend ;-)

See my questtion. Please